# Getting math domain error on my code and can't find out if the issue is identifying triangle or the formula function

Tags: python, python-3.x

a = function4(a,b,c)                if x :=  (math.sqrt((s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c))) > 0): ValueError: math domain error                      This is the error I'm getting when outputting 6,3,2, as the 3 sides from my code, as sides 6,3,2 don't form a triangle so on my function1 I put an if-else on the def function to identify a triangle true or not. I guess my code on identifying the triangle true or not isn't even right, I know something is off but can't find the issue. Thank you.

```
import math


a = int(input('Enter your first triangle side '))
b = int(input('Enter your second triangle side '))
c = int(input('Enter your third triangle side '))

def function1 (a,b,c):
    if(a+b<=c or b+c<=a or c+a<=b):
        return 1 , print('This is not a true triangle')
    elif (a+b>=c or a+c>=b or b+c>=a):
        return 0, print('This is a true triangle')

def function2 (a,b,c):
    if (a**2+b**2==c**2 or b**2+c**2==a**2 or c**2+a**2==b**2) :
        return ('This is a right triangle')
    else :
        return ('The is not a right triangle.')
    
def function3 (a,b,c):
    perimeter = int(a+b+c)
    #return('The perimeter of the triangle is '+ str(perimeter))
    return(perimeter)

tri1 = function1(a,b,c)
tri2 = function2(a,b,c)
p = function3(a,b,c)

def function4 (a,b,c):
    s = int(p/2)
    if x :=  (math.sqrt((s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c))) > 0):
        return x
    else:
        return 0
    


def large (a,b,c):
    num = (a,b,c)
    lm = max(num)
    return int(lm)
def mid(a,b,c):
    num = [a,b,c]
    ss, lm = min(num), max(num)
    num.remove(ss)
    num.remove(lm)
    return num[0]
def small (a,b,c):
    num = (a,b,c)
    sm = min(num)
    return int(sm)

small1 = small(a,b,c)
mid1 = mid(a,b,c)
large1 = large(a,b,c)

a = function4(a,b,c)

print(tri1)
print(tri2)
print('The perimeter of the triangle is ' + str(p))
print('The area of the triangle is ' +str(a))
print('Smallest Side: ' + str(small1))
print('Medium Side: ' + str(mid1))
print('Largest Side: ' + str(large1))
```

`Expect to find out why it's having math domain error and better solution to identify a true triangle and not true.`

Comment: You're trying to take the square root of a negative number.  This is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The math domain error occurs if the triangle is not true triangle because of the following reason.

Let us assume we are giving 3 values but this can't be a true triangle. say 1, 2 and 8.

so the value of  s = (1+2+8)/2 = 5.5

so the value of s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c) = (5.5)*(4.5)*(3.5)*(-2.5) = -216

so sqft(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) = sqrt(-216)

Square root can not be found out for negative value. So it gives math domain error.

The solution is with your existing code should be in function4:

```
def function4 (a,b,c):
    s = int(p/2)
    if x :=  (s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c)) > 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: The requirement is function4 has to return 0 if the triangle is not true. And the rest will also have to print if not true. For example, the output should be like this with number 6,3,2 entered. Enter your first triangle side: 6.     Enter your second triangle side: 3.         Enter your third triangle side: 2.        This is not a true triangle. This is not a right triangle. The perimeter of the triangle is 11. The area of the triangle is 0. Smallest side: 2. Medium side: 3. Largest side : 6.

Comment: @KioLin,  screenshot of the output of my code. I didn't modify anything, You yourself can copy, paste & check with different values : https://imgur.com/a/EvbnPgl  The idea of not returning zero is, if correct condition is true, naturally the incorrect condition is false. (i.e) when we asks a function to return true for the correct condition, the same function automatically returns false for the incorrect condition.

Comment: @KioLin In that case, a small correction was required to be done in your code. I've edited your code accordingly. See my answer now

Comment: I have already fixed it in another way on my own, but thank you!